# Sed in place edit

Tags: bash, sed

```
for term in `cat stopwords`; do sed -i 's/\<$term\>//g' spam.txt ;done
```

Given stopwords contains a word per line and spam.txt is plain text file, I just need to replace exact matches of stopwords. Does not behave as I expect ...
Note there are words like `doesn't`, `couldn't` in both the files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you want to run sed in for loop? I would use sed script-file.

```
TMPFILE=mktemp
for WORD in $(cat stopwords); do echo 's/'$WORD'//g' >> $TMPFILE; done
sed -f $TMPFILE spam.txt
rm -f $TMPFILE
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out ... I thought its more l33t to just do inplace replacement. But this is nice and elegant ...

Comment: Just wondering if there's a typo in this answer, I think it should be `sed -i -f $TMPFILE spam.txt` - thereby maintaining the OP's intent of performing in-place replacement, just more efficiently using a script file.

Comment: We can use `sed` to generate `$TMPFILE`: `sed 's|^|s/|;s|$|//g|' stopwords > $TMPFILE`. Then actually use it directly as a script: `sed 's|^|s/|;s|$|//g|' stopwords | sed -i -f - spam.txt`

Comment: @aragaer: That is basically [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16914949/2451238) copied to a comment.

Comment: @sh-lecram: sorry I didn't notice that answer. But the trick is so cool, I'm using it myself quite often now.

Comment: If you really want to use a `tmpfile` I recommend to ensure its removal using a trap.

Answer (score 8):

well you should use " instead of ' in your sed command. Using single quote ' tells the shell to not substitute the $term.

This :

```
for term in `cat stopwords`; do sed -i "s/\<$term\>//g" spam.txt ;done
```

Works for :

```
# stopwords
couldn't
```

and :

```
# spam.txt
foo <couldn't> bar
```

my 2 cents

Answer (score 3):

@kerolasa is onto something there.

The most important being that your $term is NOT being expanded as a variable. You can rewrite your code as

```
for term in `cat stopwords`; do sed -i "s/\<${term}\>//g" spam.txt ;done
```

But that is a very expensive opperation, you are running sed for each word that is in `stopwords`. Making a sed script per @kerolasa idea is more efficient, but it depends, if this is a one-off project, then your solution will work.

Except ... "words like doesn't, couldn't in both files", Yes, and? I'm not sure what you are saying there, what do you expect/want to happen, why do you think it won't happen? Changing your quoting will help.

Finally, note that this solution may break if your stopword list contains spaces, i.e. 'spanner in the works' ;-).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I always get confused with the quotes in bash ... and suspected the the substitution wasn't working correctly. So pointed it out ... and no space in stopwords.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a tempfile for the script as suggested by [Sami Kerola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796585), you could also pipe the script to `sed`, creating it from `stopwords` using a second instance of `sed`:

```
sed 's,.*,s/\\<&\\>//g,' stopwords | sed -i -f- spam.txt
```

Note that I used `,` instead of `/` as separator for the fist instance of `sed` to not have to quote every `/` I use as separator in the generated expression. But this is imho just a matter of taste and of course you could also use `'s/.*/s\/\\<&\\>\/\/g/'` if you like it more.